# we have completed all the steps mentioned int he url Running Apache Storm on Windows.But we didn't get input and output of the word count topology

Tags: apache-storm

we have completed all the steps mentioned int he url Running Apache Storm on Windows.But we didn't get input and output of the word count topology .Please help me to how to give the input and find the output.

Thanks,
Sowmiya
Priya

Comment: what is the issue, any exception, logs? how are you running the topology? what's on in the condole? share some code if possible, this does not clearly explain the actual problem

Comment: we have deployed the topology successfully without any error.But we don't know the location of input and output of the topology.can you please tell where the output of the topology will come?

Comment: @Chiron, think the OP is asking for trouble shooting the said topology so not sure if it is actually to be treated as an duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The `wordCount` topology keeps a map (`Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`) in memory which stores the word as `key` and the count as `value`.

Are you able to run the `ExclamationTopology` in your system?